# Does anyone know how to get rid of this eclipse error window?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, dialog, window

I have quite a few plugins installed in eclipse and about a week ago I started to get this pop-p window anytime I click a line number to go to that line of code:

[image]

In a lot of cases, it prevents me from going to the particular line. Does anyone know what is causing this error and if/how I can solve it?

I'm running Eclipse in the latest 64bit version of Ubuntu, fully updated.

Thanks in advance

Forgot to upload the error log:

[image]

Found and posting the stack trace as requested:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.core.ISourceReference.getNameRange()Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/ISourceRange;
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.setSelection(JavaEditor.java:2329)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.doSelectionChanged(JavaEditor.java:2408)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaOutlinePage$3.linkToEditor(JavaOutlinePage.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.selectionChanged(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:888)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1226)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3563)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3212)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: "See the log for more details"... What are the details? Couldn't you just disable that plugin? Did you contact the plugin developer?

Comment: As long as culprit plugins are in plugin folder, it is hard to get rid of these errors. Re-install eclipse may be the only option.

Comment: Pl. post the stacktrace from the log to understand the exact problem

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the error log. I know which plugin is causing the problem, I'm not sure if there is a fix for it, and if not, how to uninstall it.

Comment: Right click on the error log and get the properties which should have a stack trace; please post that. The plugin is the JDT plugin which does the Java development, so you will not want to uninstall it. It could be some JDT problem with one of your source files.

Comment: I've just posted the stack trace.

Comment: Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like the versions of some jars are out of whack. Try a Help > Check for Updates; bringing everything, platform and plugins, up to date might get things in line again.

Might be worth checking that the filesystem permissions are set correctly to allow the update; you need write access to all files and folders in your Eclipse installation (well, not all, but a lot of them). If permission problems stop the update, it might not stop cleanly.

Comment: As far as I know, the program and system are fully up to date, but do you know what folders I should check permissions in? I have all permissions for the basic eclipse files and folders, however, I cannot find the plugin folder

Comment: There will be one more more folders under the `plugins` folder inside your Eclipse installation. For instance, i have the Eclipse binary at `/opt/eclipse/eclipse-jee-indigo/eclipse`, and plugins are at places like `/opt/eclipse/eclipse-jee-indigo/plugins/org.moreunit_2.4.2.jar`.

Comment: Close and restarting Studio again worked for me